# How to query jsonb array with sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.4

I have data stored in a jsonb field like so:

```
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSONB)
```

In the `data` column there is a json of the form:

```js
{depth: [0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06]}
```

I want to determine the max depth for each record and came up with the following query in raw SQL which does the job:

```sql
SELECT test.id, test.name,
  (SELECT max(elem::float)
   FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(test.data -> 'depth') As elem
   ) AS maxdepth
FROM test
ORDER BY maxdepth DESC
```

As I am using SQLAlchemy ORM in my application I want to write this query with SQLAlchemy ORM, but I cannot come up with the proper form.

I was thinking I need something like this:

```
subq = session.query(
    func.max().label('maxdepth')).\
    select_from(func.jsonb_array_elements(Test.data['depth'])).\
    subquery()

stmnt = session.query(
    Test.id, subq.c.maxdepth).\
    order_by(subq.c.maxdepth)
```

But this obviously doesn't work as I don't know how to query from the fields extracted by `jsonb_array_elements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NOTE: AS OF SQLAlchemy 1.0, Oct. 26 2015.  This may change in a future release]  these special PG syntaxes are not built in to SQLAlchemy right now, please see the recipe at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3566/figure-out-how-to-support-all-of-pgs#comment-22842678 which illustrates your query.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can confirm this works. I hope you find a way to improve the built-in SQLAlchemy PG/JSON support in future releases!

Comment: I wish there was a current document that has this support documentation, as of 2019-08-08, the documentation for SQLAlchemy and JSONB is pretty hard to dig up.

Comment: I can't see this page. Is the repo private now?

Comment: The repository was moved to Github and is now here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3566#issuecomment-441931331. I'm not sure which specific comment was to be linked, but one of those in the thread should be what was intended